# Please translate Muṇḍaka Upaniṣad 1.2.10

Tags: upanishads, translation-request, sanskrit

Namaste. Could someone  translate this: tasmād etad brahma nāma-rūpam annaṁ ca jāyate [Muṇḍaka Upaniṣad 1.2.10] , please.

Comment: The above shloka is Mundaka I.1.9.

Comment: Pure translation questions are off-topic. Read [this meta discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1676/277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Mundaka Upanishad I.1.9.

> *yah sarvajnah sarva-vid yasya jnanamayam tapah; tasmad etad brahma
> nama-rupam annam ca jayate*

**Mundaka I.1.9**

*He who is all-knowing and all-wise, whose austerity consists of knowledge, from him are born this Brahma (Hiranya-garbha), name-shape and food.*

**English translation of Mundaka I.1.9**

> The all-knowing, all-wise is Isvara or the Absolute in relation to the
> world. He is wisdom, His tapas is jnana. From Him issues the world
> soul, Hiranya-garbha or Brahma.
>
> The Brahman who is without beginning and end, who is of the form of
> the indestructable word is apparently tranformed into objects, and
> this process through which creation takes place. Sphota is the
> indivisible idea with its dual form of sabda, word and artha, meaning.

**The Principal Upanishads by S. Radhakrishnan**

Comment: Dear Pradip, thank you so much. You helped me a lot (^o^).

Answer (score 1):

According to Madhvacharya,
Mundaka Upanishad, 1.1.9

tasmāt-from Him, etad Brahma-this chaturmukhi Brahmā, nāmarūpam-the name form, spirit matter, the conditioned Jiva, annam- prakrti, jāyate-is born.

Comment: Dear Krsna Dasa, thank you for your kindness.